# Warning: require_once(/home/orgdevelopers.tk/public_html/ok/app/Config/constant.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, cakephp

You can see the error on `http://orgdevelopers.tk/api/app/Config/core.php`
my php version is `7.0.33`.
I am getting this error when I execute my PHP file. Please help.

```php
{Warning: require_once(/home/orgdevelopers.tk/public_html/ok/app/Config/constant.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/orgdevelopers.tk/public_html/ok/core.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/orgdevelopers.tk/public_html/ok/app/Config/constant.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70/share/pear:/usr/local/lsws/lsphp70/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/orgdevelopers.tk/public_html/ok/core.php on line 3}

core.php line 3 is== require_once('app/Config/constant.php');
```

Comment: If both files reside in same directory, Shouldn't the path of `constant.php` in `require_once` function in `core.php` be `constant.php` or `/api/app/Config/constant.php` or `__DIR__.'/constant.php'` instead of `app/Config/constant.php`

Comment: i changed the path to require_once('constant.php') and it worked thanks for help

Comment: May I post my suggestion as answer so you can accept it?

Comment: ok i accept, your suggestion was good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both files reside in same directory, The path of `constant.php` in `require_once` function in `core.php` should be `constant.php` or `/api/app/Config/constant.php` or `__DIR__.'/constant.php'` instead of `app/Config/constant.php`